# How to determine which rows are selected in UITableView from outside didSelectRowAtIndexPath (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do I keep track which rows are currently selected in a tableview from outside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function. I also want to make sure the row is removed when the user deselects it. How is the best way to do this?

Comment: `.indexPathsForSelectedRows` -- see documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy.

**Swift:**

```
let indexPathForSelectedRows: [IndexPath]? = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

**Objective C:**

```
NSArray *indexPathForSelectedRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Comment: Do [yourDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; in your didDeselectRowAtIndexPath and then [tableView reloadData].